# Change SQL server local name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In my SQL Server 2005, i'm able to login with servername as " .\LOCAL ". How can i  change this to  " . "

I tried changing the sql server name using query *sp_dropserver and sp_addserver* but it's didn't work?

How can i change this?

Answer (score 2):

Never had to do it, but this guide looks promising:  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/

It wouldn't be a true default instance, which ultimately may make things confusing, but installing a default instance may not be an option... If it is, by all means install the default instance, move your databases and remove the named.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a named instance to a default instance. The only way to do this is to install a default instance, then backup your databases and restore them (as well as logins, jobs, linked servers, etc).

Or an alternative so that your clients can *think* they are connecting to a default instance is to make the named instance listen on a fixed port and then create network aliases (using client network utility) on all the clients that will connect.